# "Mail merge"-like functionality in Dreamweaver, or in any other web editing tool?

Tags: html, dreamweaver, data-driven

I have inherited several related, low-traffic web sites to manage and edit.  These sites are implemented with static html, and they've accrued lots of stray tags and other cruft.  I want to try to clean these up and migrate them to some common page template framework to simplify design and data changes and improve overall consistency.  The pages will change on the timescale of weeks, and since the current web hosting plan does not support any dynamic server technologies, I was hoping to just use Dreamweaver or some other tool to merge my content data with some templating structure.  I'd like to do content updates every several days and then run the content back through my templates, resulting in new static html that I can upload to the host.   Do any tools support this kind of poor-man's data-driven web application?  Are there better ways to approach this problem, aside from moving to a new hosting plan and using ASP.NET or PHP?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to write it on a local server with PHP/ASP.NET, and then simply invoke PHP or ASP.NET locally to process the page; save the resulting output to html files, and upload those (you could automate this fairly easily via a scripting language). Nothing says the ASP/PHP parser has to be run on page request; it could be run much earlier than that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver supports templates . . . take a look @ this link  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/templates.html

[Deep link to what you probably want](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/ssi_lbi_template.html)